# ¿Existe alguna forma de poner un Contador en clausula "with" del querý builder?

Tags: adonisjs, adonis-4, lucid

estoy haciendo un clon de twitter en AdonisJs y de esta manera obtengo mis "tweets" :

```js
const tweets = await Post.query()
  .whereIn('user_id', followersIds)
  .with('user')
  .with('favorites')
  .with('replies')
  .orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
  .paginate(params.page, 3)
```

el problema en esto es que cuando obtengo el resultado el tweet viene con todas las tablas y solo necesito tener el contador de cada una de ellas... Sí, podría utilizar un bucle para reemplazar cada objeto por el contador pero ¿Existe una manera más practica de hacer esto?

Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

El *ORM Lucid* cuenta con un método llamado [`withCount`](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/relationships#_counts) para obtener el conteo de relaciones.

Entonces debes seguir una sintaxis como la siguiente:

```
await Modelo.query().withCount('nombreRelacion').fetch()
```

Con el punto anterior podemos tomar tu query y reescribirla de esta forma:

```
const tweets = await Post.query()
                         .whereIn('user_id', [followersIds])
                         .withCount('user')
                         .withCount('favorites')
                         .withCount('replies')
                         .orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                         .paginate(params.page, 3)
```